# Perspective Transformation of a Point in 2D Plane in Python

Tags: python, perspective

I have the following image where the four corners of the cattle housing are -[(x1,y1), (x2,y2), (x3,y3), (x4,y4)]. The camera to capture the image was positioned in the middle of the (x1,y1) and (x4,y4). As the (x3,y3) and (x2,y2) are far from the camera, in the image, x1-x4 not equal  x2-x3.

[image]

I need to reproject the housing into a 2d rectangular plane with corners of [(x1,y1), (x2,y2), (x3,y3), (x4,y4)] and unlikely the original image, this new plane will have x1-x4 = x2-x3. Is there any viable option to do that? OpenCV comes with a perspective transformation function that can only be applied to an image. But, in this case, I will have some x,y locations of cattle on the original plane which need to be converted and drawn into the rectangular 2d plane to show the cattle position.

Answer (score 2):

This problem is linear algebra more than programming.  You have a linear transformation on a simple quadrilateral.  The math is simpler, because you have two edges parallel to edges of the image.

First of all, we need to redefine some notation: for instance, you've used (x2, y2) to refer to both points on the posted image, *and* to the desired position of the upper-left corner of the transformed image.  I will simplify this by declaring the transformed points to be A = (x1, y2) and B = (x4, y3): we're horizontally stretching the top of the trapezoid to form a rectangle.

Also note that y1=y4 and y2=y3 from the start; this simplifies the calculations.  Visualize the new and old images overlaid, with a point of question `Q` in the interior, its coordinates marked on the boundary.  We need to find the general equation for `Q`'s transformed point, `R`, after the "stretching".

I have also marked the median of the original image, `MN`.  Points on this line will not move during the stretching.  As a side note, points along the bottom edge `1-4` will not move.  Points on the outer fringes of `2-3` will move most.  Let `C` be the point on edge `1-2` with the same y-coordinate as `Q` (and, later, `R`); let `D` be the corresponding point on `MN`.

```
A-----2-----M-----3---B
|                     |
Qy  CR  Q  D          |
|                     |
|                     |
1----Rx-Qx-N----------4
```

We merely need to pro-rate the amount that a chosen point moves.  Finding the equations of `MN` and `1-2` are well-known (two-point formula).  Substitute `Qy` into each of those equations to obtain `Cx` and `Dx`.

The "stretch" factor, in transforming `CD` to `(x1, Qy) D` is the ratio of their lengths: `(Dx-x1) / (Dx-Cx)`.  `Q` will move left by a proportion of that stretch factor, according to its distance left of D: `(Dx-Qx) / (Dx-x1)`.  Multiply those to get the distance Q moves.  Subtract that amount from `Qx` to get `Rx`.

Yes, you now have several constants in the final, combined equation: x1, x2, x3, x4, y1, y2.  You also have variables Qx and Qy.  This is as it should be.  This leaves you with a general equation to convert Qx => Rx for any point in the image.

If you plan to stretch vertically as well, the same proportioning will apply in the vertical direction.  I suggest that you do one stretch at a time; this will keep the math modular: easier to check and debug in separate stages.

Does that get you moving?

`D` will not move;

Comment: Nice answer! Plenty of relevant detail to help the OP on their way, but not simply giving them a free. coded solution, which seems right as they didnt make any effort to show any code they had attempted, upvote.

Comment: @barny I was looking for the answer provided by Prune . Currently, I am using a completely different solution but that's not very accurate. I can deal with X co-ordinates but not the Y coordinate using my approach. I needed to know other possible ways of solving it.